# LCD driver program in Verilog for Altera DE2 board

Tags: verilog, fpga

I need to display the characters and numbers on a `2x16` LCD on the Altera DE2 board using a Verilog program. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started!

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.arch.fpga/msg/f4ef5805dbafbcc9

Answer (score 1):

This project will probably get you 90% of the way... http://opencores.org/project,wb_lcd